# how can i spawn a process that lives only for given duration

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, createprocess

I have a parent process and I'd like to spawn the child process for a certain duration ( say N milli seconds). I'm doing this in c++ (and windows).

Can I provide some parameter to [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that would kill it after a while and return control to the parent application ? If not, is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can I provide some parameter to CreateProcess...?*

Yes, you may pass the desired `duration` (N) with the parameter *lpCommandLine* to the process to be started.

The child process may parse *lpCommandLine* and set up a timer with the desired
`duration`. This timer could for example be a [Waitable Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or simply a thread with

```
Sleep(duration);               // waits the duration
ExitProcess(GetLastError());   // exits the "remote" process
```

The thread (a thread inside the the child process) terminates the entire child process after `duration`. The WaitableTimer idea would need a frequent call to a wait function. See [Using Waitable Timer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

**But:** The parent process will remain "in control" all the time. 
**However:** You may additionally
enter a wait state in the parent process, using a wait function (e.g. [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), waiting on the child processes handle to actually hibernate the parent process until the child process terminates. On top you may evaluate the return value of the child process by a call to the [GetExitCodeProcess function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The described schemes ensures that the desired `duration` is best performed, however, you may also control the `duration` from the parent process by means of a named event. See [Using Event Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details. In such an approach, the parent process may set an event when the `duration` "is consumed". The child process waits for that event and terminates when the event was set. This approach may be a little less accurate since the parent doesn't quite know when the childs `duration` started.

**Example with waitable timer:**

Parent process:

```
...
#define CHILD_DURATION 2000  // 2000 ms    

HANDLE hProcess;
char ChildName[MAX_PATH];
char CommandLine[MAX_PATH];

sprintf_s(ChildName,MAX_PATH,"MyChild.exe");
sprintf_s(CommandLine,MAX_PATH,"%d",CHILD_DURATION);

// start the child 
hProcess = CreateProcess(ChildProcessName,CommandLine,....
if (0 == hProcess)
{
  // error with process creation
  printf("CreateProcessfailed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
  return GetLastError();
}

// and wait for it to finish
if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(hProcess,INFINITE) 
{
  // child finished
} else
{
  // error with wait
  printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
  return GetLastError();
}  
...
```

Child process:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    HANDLE hWaitableTimer CreateWaitableTimer(NULL,TRUE,NULL);
    if (NULL == hWaitableTimer)
    {
        printf("CreateWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return GetLastError();
    }

    DWORD dwDuration = atoi(argv[1]);
    LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime = -10000 * dwDuration; 
    // waitable timer due time is in 100 nano second units
    // negative values indicate relative time
    if (!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0))
    {
        printf("SetWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return GetLastError();
    }

    DWORD dwKeepGoing = TRUE;
    // enter the "to do" loop while waiting for the timer...
    While (dwKeepGoing) 
    {
        switch (WaitForSingleObject(hTimer,0) 
        {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                // duration over, 
                // optionally finalize "to do" stuff here 
                // and end child
                dwKeepGoing = FALSE;

            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                // do stuff here
                break;

            case WAIT_FAILED:
                // the wait function has failed                     
                printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
                return GetLastError();
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to talk about this here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43987/child-process

Answer (score 1):

Noone will kill the process for you, unless you either do it on your own (e.g. from parent process), or the process exits itself.

Note that there is also no such thing as "and return control to the parent application". Once child process is started, both parent and child processes have their own "control" and run simultaneously, consuming CPU time given to the processes by the operating system.

All in all, you decide who will be terminating the process. If you do it from parent process, then once started you keep child process handle and use (not a good idea though) [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API toward the child process.

Otherwise, and this is the better one, the child process itself keep looking at runtime and just exits when it's time to do so:

```
main() {
  time_to_exit = now() + N;
  while(now() < time_to_exit) {
    keep_doing_my_stuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to run the child process for a very specific time, since I am measuring latency for a certain operation. Due time slicing, it sounds like, I cannot be precise in doing so ?

Comment: Spawning a process is a bulky operation incomparable to time slice durations. To be precise on milliseconds you most likely do not even want to spawn processes and instead rethink how you can do it another way.

Comment: I think Arno in below's answer also recommended handling the child process duration within the child only.